# c# case insensitive dictionary on model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, webapi

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

If I do the above it will make a case insensitive dictionary.

But how can I achieve same in case of model binding in webapi.

Model will be

```
class Model{
   Dictionary<string,string> d;
}
```

Is there a way to attribute or something like the above dictionary's keys are case insensitive

Thanks
Binesh

Comment: You will likely need to add a custom model binder. If you include an [mcve] it might be easier to point you in the correct direction.

Comment: Hi @Igor
Thanks for the response. I'm having a payload, which have only one dictionary. While posting I'm getting dictionary filled even. But when I do a validation Guid.TryParse(payload.KeyValuePairs["value"], out value), its asking me for correct case. My customer may type "Value", "VALUE","value" etc.. any. if invarientcultureignorecase it would be worked. But i'm not creating the dictionary. model binder do for me. So I'm looking something "hey model binder while creating this dictionary for me please make it case insensitive"

Comment: It sounds like you will probably have to implement a [custom binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0). In doing so, you can enforce insensitive string comparison within the constructor for that Dictionary property

Comment: @BineshNambiarC Can you pls post your webapi header code and what version net are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a json constructor to your class

```
 public class ViewModel
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> d { get; set; } =
            new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        [JsonConstructor]
        public ViewModel(Dictionary<string, string> d)
        {
            foreach (var item in d)
                this.d.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }
```